# Postgresql: display values in jsonb array column as CSV

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, csv, jsonb

I have a jsonb column that is used to store an array of value:

```
["value1", "value2", "value3"]
```

I would like to concatenate the values inside that array with the value of another column, such as instead of having:

```
string column | jsonb column
--------------+-------------------------------
   mystring   | ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
```

I can have:

```
           string + jsonb
------------------------------------
   mystring, value1, value2, value3
```

I naively tried using jsonb_array_elements to no avail.

```
SELECT string_column || ', ' || jsonbvalues
FROM mytable, jsonb_array_elements(mytable.jsonb_column) as jsonbvalues
```

Could someone indicate what the correct syntax is?

Answer (score 1):

The function `json_array_elements()` returns set, so you need an aggregate function. 
An aggregation will be correct if the column it is grouped by is unique.

The query below assumes that `string_column` is unique.

```
SELECT format('%s, %s', string_column, string_agg(jsonbvalues, ', ')) result
FROM (
    SELECT string_column, jsonbvalues
    FROM mytable, jsonb_array_elements_text(mytable.jsonb_column) as jsonbvalues
    ) sub
GROUP BY string_column;

              result              
----------------------------------
 mystring, value1, value2, value3
(1 row)
```

If `string_column` is not unique, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable;

 string_column |          jsonb_column          
---------------+--------------------------------
 mystring      | ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
 mystring      | ["value4", "value5", "value6"]
(2 rows)
```

you can use `row_number()` to identify original rows:

```
SELECT format('%s, %s', string_column, string_agg(jsonbvalues, ', ')) result
FROM (
    SELECT rn, string_column, jsonbvalues
    FROM (
        SELECT *, row_number() over () as rn
        FROM mytable
        ) t, 
        jsonb_array_elements_text(jsonb_column) as jsonbvalues
    ) sub
GROUP BY rn, string_column;

              result              
----------------------------------
 mystring, value1, value2, value3
 mystring, value4, value5, value6
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, wasn't it what you wanted?