# PostgreSQL: Print JSON array as CSV

Tags: sql, arrays, json, string, postgresql

This question is similar to [A] but goes a little deeper.

Let's assume a table `mytable` with a single column `data` of type `jsonb` containing JSON arrays of strings:

```
data
----
['olaf','anna']
['elsa','kristoff','sven']
```

I would like to print them as comma-separated lists:

```
data_csv
--------
'olaf,anna'
'elsa,kristoff,sven'
```

If `mytable` had an ID column, then [A] would essentially work which proposed a combination of `jsonb_array_elements` and `group by`:

```
select
  id,
  string_agg(j.value->>0, ',')
from
  mytable m,
  jsonb_array_elements(x.z) j
group by m.id;
```

But even if we had an `id` column, this solution does not seem very efficient as it involves a nested loop:

[image]

How could we do it without an ID column and, even more important, how can we do it efficiently? Can this maybe be achieved with the help of PL/pgSQL?

[A] [Postgresql: display values in jsonb array column as CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34107069/postgresql-display-values-in-jsonb-array-column-as-csv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unnest and aggregate. A lateral join might be more efficient than outer aggregation (and it does not require the table to have a primary key):

```
select t.*, d.data_csv
from mytable t
cross join lateral (
    select string_agg(val, ',') data_csv
    from jsonb_array_elements_text(t.data) x(val)
) d
```

Comment: Ah nice, this is indeed a great improvement! But is it optimal? The query plan still shows a nested loop - can we do better?

Comment: @CC.: not that I can think of right now... Apart, of course, converting the json array to its string representation (like `data::text`), and then applying string functions to remove the surrounding square brackets. But that sounds rather dirty.